# Can't add an apple account to the visual studio 2017

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, apple-id

I have an apple account, I'm trying to add an apple account to visual studio, but get an error "There was an error while trying to log in: Could not connect to the server".

my steps:
Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Apple Accounts -> add -> [insert appleId and password] -> Login

Then Error apearing

Comment: VS 2019 has released, you could update the IDE to the latest version and try again .

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to stay in this version, do you have any idea why the error appears?

Comment: Most of the similar issue will been solved after updating .